# Insert one table values to query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Have table  **myTbl** with values

```
ID  Number
1    12458
2    45896  
3    12458
4    87456
```

Have query like :

```
SELECT TOP 1 n.abonent_name , ad.address
FROM dbo.names n 
INNER JOIN dbo.addresses ad on n.address_id = ad.id
WHERE n.number = (every number from myTbl)
```

Want insert into query **Where clause** each number from myTbl and then insert response for each number to virtual table **#tbl** for example **insert into #tbl abonent_name and  address where number = 12458** , after this insert ,write in where clause another number 45896 then insert into #tbl and etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(
   id identity(1,1),
   abonent_name varchar(20),
   address varchar(50)
)
```

Want write it without cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 n.abonent_name , ad.address
FROM dbo.names n 
INNER JOIN dbo.addresses ad on n.address_id = ad.id
WHERE n.number IN (SELECT number from myTbl)
```

try above. But you can kill two birds with one stone by doing the following

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by n.abonent_name) AS ID, n.abonent_name , ad.address
INTO #tbl
FROM dbo.names n 
INNER JOIN dbo.addresses ad on n.address_id = ad.id
WHERE n.number IN (SELECT number from myTbl)
```

Comment: I'm confused about the Top 1 clause however. Why would you use Top 1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a cursor.
If there can be more that 1 row per name in the `addresses` table, you can use the following pattern:

```
INSERT INTO #tbl (abonent_name, address)
SELECT x.abonent_name, x.address
from
(
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.abonent_name
                         ORDER BY n.abonent_name, x.address) AS RowNumber,
      n.abonent_name,
      ad.address
    FROM dbo.names n 
    INNER JOIN myTbl tbl on n.number = tbl.number
    INNER JOIN dbo.addresses ad on n.address_id = ad.id
) x
where x.RowNumber = 1
order by x.RowNumber;
```

This code will insert into the *`#tbl`* table the first (alphabetical) address for each name which code exists in the *`myTbl`* table. Names will be sorted in alphabetical order ascending. Condition `x.RowNumber=1` will filter the first address in case of multiple matches.